# Custom adapter me suma filas al hacer scroll

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

He creado mi clase custom adapter, la cual se encarga de cargar los elementos personalizados dentro de mi listview.

```
public class Adaptador_calidades extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private Context appContext;
private int layout;
private Cursor c;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;
int xCajas, xPeso;
double xPrecio,xFinal;

public Adaptador_calidades(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.layout = layout;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.c = c;

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView Cajas = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.calCajas);
    TextView Precio = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.calPrecio);
    TextView Peso = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.calPeso);
    TextView Nombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemCalidad);
    TextView Codigo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.codCalidad);

   //Datos desde sqlite, los mostramos en el listview personalizado
    Cajas.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("cajas")));
    Precio.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("precio")));
    Peso.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("peso")));
    Nombre.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nombre")));
    Codigo.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));

    xCajas = xCajas + Integer.parseInt((c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("cajas"))));
    xPeso = xPeso + Integer.parseInt((c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("peso"))));
    xPrecio = xPrecio + Double.parseDouble((c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("precio"))));

    //Calculamos el peso
         if (!Peso.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !Precio.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
             xFinal = xFinal + (Double.parseDouble(Peso.getText().toString()) * Double.parseDouble(Precio.getText().toString()));
         }

         Separacion_App Calidades = (Separacion_App) context; //Mando la suma al textview total
         Calidades.setDatos(xCajas, xPeso, xPrecio, xFinal);
}
```

Constructor que recibe la información y la muestra en el total:

```
public void setDatos(int xCajas, int xPeso, double xPrecio, double xFinal) {
        iCajas.setText(String.valueOf(xCajas));
        iPeso.setText(String.valueOf(xPeso));
        iPrecio.setText(String.valueOf(xPrecio));
        CostoFinal = String.valueOf(xFinal);
}
```

> Mandar llamar mi adaptador

```
public void ConsultarCalidad() {
    try {
        Cursor cursor = basededatos.ConsultarCalidad();
        if (cursor == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Se ha presentado un problema al cargar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) { 
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ningún elemento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        String[] columns = new String[]{
                basededatos.COLUMN_NOMBRE,
                basededatos.COLUMN_IDCALIDAD,
                basededatos.COLUMN_CAJAS,
                basededatos.COLUMN_PESO,
                basededatos.COLUMN_PRECIO
        };

        int[] boundTo = new int[]{
                R.id.itemCalidad,
                R.id.codCalidad,
                R.id.calCajas,
                R.id.calPeso,
                R.id.calPrecio
        };

//Mando llamar a mi customadapter anter mencionado.
        customAdapter = new Adaptador_calidades(this, R.layout.item_calidad, cursor, columns, boundTo);
        ListCalidades.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Se ha producido un error "+ex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Creo que es lo más importante por mencionar. Al parecer todo esta en el *bindView* o algún otro método que pueda utilizar? Cuando doy a guardar del `dialog` vuelvo a llamar después al método `ConsultarCalidad()`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es el problema?

Comment: Y qué es lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: La pregunta es cuando quieres que te sume?

Comment: eso es lo de menos david, lo unico que no quiero esque me este sumando cada que dezplado.

Comment: @ManuelMorales es muy importante lo que pregunta David, ¿Cuando quieres que si sume?

Comment: @DavidMinaya es importante lo que preguntas, ya que si no es importante en realidad con lo que comenta el OP la respuesta entonces es comentar el calculo de Resultado y eso resuelve el "problema".

Comment: La suma se realiza cada vez que haces scroll porque el método `bindView()` se ejecuta cada vez que se crea un nuevo item (cada vez que aparece un nuevo item en pantalla). Cuando realizas scroll, aparecen nuevos item en pantalla (se crean), por lo tanto el método `bindView()` se ejecuta y la suma se vuelve a realizar. Por eso es importante saber cuando quieres que se realice la suma, porque puede que quieras que se sume el valor de todos los items de una vez o no, lo cual no esta claro. Debes poder proporcionar mas información para poder darte una respuesta.

Comment: ¿como puedo entonces controlar eso? solo quiero que me sume una ves, no al hacer scroll

Comment: @ManuelMorales ¿Podrías **[edit]** tu pregunta aclarando esto? (Y quizás un poco más de detalles también)

Comment: @ManuelMorales Agrega de que forma muestras el total también. Agrega el .xml

Comment: Ni siquiera se entiende bien **qué es lo que se suma**. Dices que *quieres que se sume una vez*, pero **¿qué, cuándo, dónde?**. Como han dicho los compañeros, faltan datos en la pregunta.

Comment: listo, ya he modificado mi pregunto.

Comment: @ManuelMorales gracias por editar tu pregunta en realidad es sencillo resolver el problema pero necesitabamos conocer mas infornación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En mi opinión, no deberías hacer dichos calculos en el `adapter`, la responsabilidad del `adapter` deberia ser ***adaptar*** los datos a los elementos de visualizacion que hayas decidido usar.

Dicho esto, en lugar de mantener los totales en el adapter, simplemente recorrerias el cursor para calcular los totales:

```
public void ConsultarCalidad() {
    try {
        Cursor cursor = basededatos.ConsultarCalidad();
        if (cursor == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Se ha presentado un problema al cargar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) { 
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ningún elemento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //calcular totales

            int xCajas, xPeso;
            double xPrecio,xFinal;

            do {
                int peso = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("peso")));
                double precio = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("precio")));
                xPeso += peso;
                xPrecio += precio;
                xCajas += Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("cajas")));

                xFinal += peso * precio;

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            setDatos(xCajas, xPeso, xPrecio, xFinal);
        }

        String[] columns = new String[]{
                basededatos.COLUMN_NOMBRE,
                basededatos.COLUMN_IDCALIDAD,
                basededatos.COLUMN_CAJAS,
                basededatos.COLUMN_PESO,
                basededatos.COLUMN_PRECIO
        };

        int[] boundTo = new int[]{
                R.id.itemCalidad,
                R.id.codCalidad,
                R.id.calCajas,
                R.id.calPeso,
                R.id.calPrecio
        };

        //Mando llamar a mi customadapter anter mencionado.
        customAdapter = new Adaptador_calidades(this, R.layout.item_calidad, cursor, columns, boundTo);
        ListCalidades.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Se ha producido un error "+ex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente, justo lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias.